# Android Move Image if Button Pressed

Tags: android, image, onclick, pressed

I want to move the player image when the upbutton is pressed. I tried the onClick() method, but it doesn't work. 
The player should move up for some pixels when the upbutton is pressed.
I tried something like getButtonState which I have seen on the Android Developer Page,
but I did not understand how this works...
Any suggestions?

```
private Context mContext;
int enemy_x = -1;
int enemy_y = -1;
int player_x = -1;
int player_y = -1;

private int enemy_xVelocity = 15;
private int enemy_yVelocity = 0;
private int player_xVelocity = 0;
private int player_yVelocity = 10;
private Handler h;
private final int FRAME_RATE = 60;

Button upbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upbutton);

public AnimatedView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mContext = context;
    h = new Handler();
}

private Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        invalidate();
    }
};

protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
    BitmapDrawable enemy = (BitmapDrawable) mContext.getResources()
            .getDrawable(R.drawable.enemy);
    BitmapDrawable player = (BitmapDrawable) mContext.getResources()
            .getDrawable(R.drawable.player);

    // enemy movement
    if (enemy_x < 0 && enemy_y < 0) {
        enemy_x = this.getWidth() / 2;
        enemy_y = this.getHeight() / 2;
    } else {
        enemy_x += enemy_xVelocity;
        enemy_y += enemy_yVelocity;
        if ((enemy_x > this.getWidth() - enemy.getBitmap().getWidth())
                || (enemy_x < 0)) {
            enemy_xVelocity = enemy_xVelocity * -1;
        }
        if ((enemy_y > this.getHeight() - enemy.getBitmap().getHeight())
                || (enemy_y < 0)) {
            enemy_yVelocity = enemy_yVelocity * -1;
        }
    }

    // player movement

    if (player_x < 0 && player_y < 0) {
        player_x = (this.getWidth() / 2) - 20;
        player_y = this.getHeight() - 150;
    } else {


        player_x += player_xVelocity;
        player_y += player_yVelocity;
        if ((player_x > this.getWidth() - player.getBitmap().getWidth())
                || (player_x < 0)) {
            player_xVelocity = player_xVelocity * -1;
        }
        if ((player_y > this.getHeight() - player.getBitmap().getHeight())
                || (player_y < 0)) {
            player_yVelocity = 0;
        }

    }

    c.drawBitmap(enemy.getBitmap(), enemy_x, enemy_y, null);
    c.drawBitmap(player.getBitmap(), player_x, player_y, null);
    h.postDelayed(r, FRAME_RATE);
}
```

Comment: "but it doesn't work".  Possibly the most useless statement in development.  What happened?  Your app crashed?  The player moved down instead of up? The sun stopped shining?  Your phone melted?  The cat ran away?

Comment: Mr. Fluffy Boots ran away?!?! :(